# Custom Jquery drop down menu lags on server sent data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q13bhq1t/) custom made jQuery dropdown menu. The example on the fiddle is okay but when I use `$.get` and `$.post` to get/post data from/on the server, 1 out of 5 time the drop down menu appears even when the mouse is not on the required position.

```
//My Script
$('#menubar ul li').hover(function() {
    $('.meicon').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find($('.meicon')).addClass('active');
    $('#menucont').fadeIn().css('left', function() {
        return ($('body').width()-$(this).width())/2;
    });

    $('#menucont').hover(function() {
        $(this).show();
    }, function(e) {
        getOut(e)
    });
}, function(e) {
    getOut(e)
});

$('#menubar, #menucont').mouseleave(function(e) {
    getOut(e)
});

function getOut(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var related = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
    var entity = $(related).prop('tagName');
    var target = $(related).attr('id');

    if (entity !== 'HTML' && entity !== 'DIV') 
        return;

    $('#menucont').hide();

    if (target == 'menucont') 
        return;

    $('.meicon').removeClass('active');
}
```

I tried to use a flag but I was unsuccessful. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a fiddle.. ?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q13bhq1t/) is it.

Comment: If the fiddle doesn't represent the problem it is pretty much useless.  You reference an issue with `get` and `post` but yet there is nothing in your code containing that?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I understand. But I think it is impossible to make a fiddle for `get` and `post`. Plus, I wanted to simplify the code as much as I can.

Comment: You can make mock ajax requests in jsFiddle - have a  search for examples.  But it is totally futile us trying to help you in the fiddle if you cannot reproduce the problem!